# stable way to increase number on input box with number

Tags: c#, selenium

Html of input box with type number looks as below

```
<input id="noofItems" type="number" max="99" min="1" class="form-control" data-bind="value: noofItems" />
```

In my selenium test i have code which inputs number in that input box

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "noofItems"), CacheLookup]
private HtmlElement ItemsInput;

ItemsInput.WaitForVisible().SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
ItemsInput.WaitForVisible().SendKeys(Keys.Control + "x");
ItemsInput.WaitForVisible().SendKeys("2");
ItemsInput.WaitForVisible().SendKeys(Keys.Return); // need this to reload dom
ItemsInput.Click();
```

by default input box has value 1 but when test runs then i want to change to 2. But sometimes value changes to 12 instead of 2.

How to resolve this? I am using chromedriver.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more about `WaitForVisible()` method would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However as you are invoking `SendKeys()` to a `<input>` tag ideally you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm).

Again, instead of using `Id` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input.form-control#noofItems"), CacheLookup]
  private HtmlElement ItemsInput;
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[@class='form-control and @id='noofItems'']"), CacheLookup]
  private HtmlElement ItemsInput;
  ```

Finally, instead of using `Keys.Control + "a"` and `Keys.Control + "x"` you can use the much proven and robust [`Clear()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Clear.htm) method as follows:

```
ItemsInput.WaitForVisible().Click(); //preferably wait for ElementToBeClickable()
ItemsInput.Clear();
ItemsInput.SendKeys("2");
ItemsInput.SendKeys(Keys.Return);
```

**PS**: Once the element is returned after being *clickable* you can invoke `Clear()` and `SendKeys()` simultaneously without any further waiters.

Comment: but isnt Id attribute more robust than anything else as it directly pinpoints element on page

Comment: I have also embedded the link of the detailed discussion wrt Id/Css/XPath in the answer itself within [`Locator Strategies`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)

Comment: None of solution worked which you provided :( Infact looks like this is working ItemsInput.SendKeys(Keys.Backspace);   
                ItemsInput.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

It seems the default value returns if the field is empty. You can try to change it without deleting it

```
ItemsInput.WaitForVisible().SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
ItemsInput.WaitForVisible().SendKeys("2");
```

As a work around, you can also set the `value` attribute with `JavaScript`

```
driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1]);", ItemsInput, 2);
```

Comment: workaround doesnt work. May be because value is binded by knockout observable.